# Genymotion 2.0 "drag and drop"

Tags: genymotion

anyone tried this website to install Google play store and works?
http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/

The drag and drop doesn't work as it just shows a "no entry" sign whenever I try to drop an apk or zip file on the home-screen.

any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su)

Answer (score 68):

You can't drag and drop under windows if one application is started as administrator.
Start Genymotion without administrator and it will work.

More about that: http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/15434-drag-drop-problem.html

Comment: Also you can start any file explorer with administrative rights (Total commander, WinSCP, Explorer, etc.). I used WinSCP. Just drag file from there.

Answer (score 34):

Open Oracle VM Virtual Box, right click on your device emulator and click on shared folders, and create a folder to share with the emulador. Check the auto mount option.

After this, reboot your emulator and try to use drag' and drop again.

That works for me.

Comment: You will be able to transfer files but not to install flashable zips.

Comment: @Bruno, Hmm, I've tried this but still it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open Oracle VM Virtual Box that was installed with GenyMotion (or manually).
Select the emulator and go to "configuration -> Advanced" and check "enable drag and drop" or something like that.
Relaunch the emulator and drag n drop should be available !

Enjoy !

Comment: No, This won't work. genymotion use a different kind of window, so a different kind of drag and drop. This settings will do nothing for Genymotion.

Comment: Well it worked for me so ... You need to check the "enable drag and drop" for the specific Genymotion emulator (in the Oracle VM Virtual Box settings) !

Answer (score 0):

@superwayne you're right ...

> You can't drag and drop under windows if one application is started as
>   administrator. Start Genymotion without administrator and it will
>   work.

But, In my Windows 10, (I do not know why), Genymotion always start as Administrator, then my solution was:

1. Run any explorer process as Administrator
2. Drag a file from that application, which is **also run as administrator**

Comment: How does one start an explorer process as an administrator?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using **custom ANTROIDSTUDIO SDK.**

So change this into **Genymotion default Android tools**

> Open Genymotion  Click `Settings` --> `ADB`
>
> **select default Genymotion Android tools**

Answer (score -1):

Drag'n'Drop feature is available since Genymotion 2.0.

Comment: I'm using 2.0.1 but cant seem to use the feature

Comment: You need to have the last Genymotion images for devices too.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. Try to update your Genymotion.

Comment: I have the latest Genymotion installed but still unable to use the drag and drop feature. Is there anything needed to be set up before it can be done?

Comment: Same problem, simple doesn't work, but in my case if is giving a `An error occured while deploying a file. Error: device not found.` error.