# How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, genymotion

VmHow can I install Google Play Services in a Genymotion emulator with no drag and drop support?

I can't install it as mentioned in Stack Overflow post *[How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990)* due to the lack of support for drag and drop installation.

Genymotion supports Google Apps for a few emulators, but it doesn't support tablet emulators.

Comment: Genymotion dropped GApps and ARM Support on all their VMs, not some. The guide you're linking to is how to get them back. If you can't Drag&Drop that means you don't have the Android SDK installed on your PC. If you have a problem regarding a specific answer, just comment next time instead of making a whole new question.

Comment: Your comment about this topic is really helpful thanks. Next time I will just comment instead of making new question .

Comment: in case you have issues with the drag and drop read this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002138/genymotion-2-0-drag-and-drop

Comment: see this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Comment: Please follow to the detailed instruction: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virt)

Comment: Best place to find play services for your device http://opengapps.org/. Choose x86 for genymotion

Comment: Official way is mentioned in the Genymotion FAQ: https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#google-play-services
(See Mahesh N's post below.)

Answer (score 981, accepted):

As of Genymotion 2.10.0 and onwards, GApps can be installed from the emulator toolbar.
Please refer to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45455999/2099146) by @[MichaelStoddart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3494639/michaelstoddart).

Next follows former answer kept here for historic reason:

Genymotion doesn't provide Google Apps. To install Google Apps:

1. Upgrade Genymotion and VirtualBox to the latest version.
2. Download two zip files:

    - ARM Translation Installer v1.1

    - **Google Apps for your Android version**: [2.3.7 - 4.4.4](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps) or [4.4 - 6.0 (with platform and variant)](http://opengapps.org/) You can also find the GApps list in the **wbroek** user [GitHubGist page](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145).
3. Open Genymotion emulator and go to home screen then drag and drop the first file **Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip** over the emulator. A dialog will appear and show as file transfer in progress, then another dialog will appear and ask that do you want to flash it on the emulator. Click OK and reboot the device by running `adb reboot` from your terminal or command prompt.
4. Drag and drop the second file **gapps-*-signed.zip** and repeat the same steps as above. Run `adb reboot` again and, once rebooted, Google Apps will be in the emulator.
5. **At this point 'Google Apps Services' will crash frequently** with the following message `google play services has stopped working`. Open Google Play. After providing your account details, open Google Play and update your installed Google Apps. This seems to make Google Play realize you have an old Google Play Services and will ask you to update (in my case, **updating Google Hangouts required a new version of Google Play Services**). I've also heard that simply waiting will also prompt you to update. The 'Google Play Services' app doesn't seem to appear otherwise - you can't search for it. You should then see an offer to update Google Play Services. Once the new Google Play Services is installed you will now have stable, working access to Google Play

Comment: Thank! Btw, drap & drop worked from anywhere for me on ubuntu

Comment: Which version of ubuntu you are using ?

Comment: I am Using ubuntu 13.04 32 bit but in my experience drag and drop supports only from the desktop .

Comment: The "Galaxy Nexus-4.2.2 with google apps-Api 17 -720x1280" does _not_ include the Google Play service.

Comment: @anp8850 Thank you for the elucidation though the drag and drop solution does not work for me.  Per your tip, I installed two emulators supporting Google Apps: 1. Nexus 7 - 4.2.2 - with Google Apps - API17; 2. WXGA 10.1 Tablet - 4.2.2 - with Google Apps - API17. Google Play service works fine on both emulators.

Comment: It says "Oppss! Something went wrong while grabbing gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip" why could it be?

Comment: Please check the genymotion's android version and drag and drop the correct zip file.

Comment: How does one do `adb reboot`?

Comment: @anp8850 I did this and it worked perfectly. But were you able to register your device? Everything, except for Google+ works perfectly, but when I go to play.google.com/settings, there are no devices showing :( How do I get it to register? :(

Comment: @PeterRaeves Use the following command `adb connect 192.168.56.101` followed by `adb -e reboot`. `-e` is important such that, to tell adb channel reboot command to connected virtual device.

Comment: Drag and drop isn't working for me. "Invalid filename". See print: http://s8.postimg.org/9uuab4c8l/Screen_Shot_2014_08_19_at_4_13_31_AM.png

Comment: followed instructions, but GPS keeps on crashing even after update, and its services are practically unusable.

Comment: In order to update Google Play, you can open Google Play, go to _Settings_ and click on the _Build Version_.

Comment: If you want to update Google Play services, in the browser on the phone, search for "Google Play Services" and the first result should be a link to the Google Play Services on the play store.  You can update it there.

Comment: Thanks @Wilf, gapps-kk-signed.zip don't install Play Store indeed, but  gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip does

Comment: I experimented with several GM images (Android 4.4, 4.2, 2.3) and gapps without success, but finally this worked for me: "Google Galaxy Nexus - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 720x1280" and gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip. After the second reboot google install wizard started on powerup, no services crashes or whatsoever, entered google login/password in wizard and apps started upgrading immediately. Genymotion 2.3.0, Virtualbox 4.3.14 on ArchLinux x86_64

Comment: I successfully installed "Google Play Services" on Android 4.3 and 4.1.1. But I can't figure out how to correctly install Android 2.3 series. In my case, I downloaded the package `gapps-gb-20110828-signed.zip` and create the virtual device `Samsung Galaxy Note-2.3.7-API 10-800x1280` and cannot find **Google Play** app after the installation... Any help?

Comment: @RalphZhouYuan I use https://gingerdx.googlecode.com/files/gapps-gb-20130120-signed.zip successfully with "Google Nexus S - 2.3" virtual device. But you DON'T needs to install "ARM Translation Installer v1.1".

Comment: When I drag n drop this zip files, I've got alert "file successfully copied to...", nothing about flashing. Google Nexus 9 emulator, android 5.0.0

Comment: For those having difficulty mapping the CyanogenMod versions to the Android OS versions, it's indicated by two of the letters in the filename, e.g. the "kk" in gapps-**kk**-20140105-signed.zip indicates it's KitKat, **lp** -> Lollipop, **jb** -> Jellybean, etc..

Comment: I needed to switch to 'use custom Android SDK tools' under Genymotion settings to be able to use adb in command line

Comment: [Google Apps for Android 5.1](http://highonandroid.com/download-android-5-1-lollipop-gapps/)

Comment: I dragged and dropped **Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip**, but it just showed successfully transfer and no message to confirm flashing. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Chenghua, Just check if the ZIP file is valid archive? May be the file is not correctly downloaded and you may need to re-download.

Comment: Like Chenghua saig, after drag&dropping nothing happens, the zip just sits in /sdcard/Downloads/ on Genymotion 2.5.0.

Comment: For some reason adb reboot takes forever to restart the VM for me, I usually just kill and restart through Genymotion

Comment: @anp8850 I have nexus 7 2013 5.1.1 image and GApps and store installed fine with Gaps 5.1 version but every time i start it it shows Apps updating dialog , what must be wrong ?

Comment: @anp8850 what i can do after the drag and drop both two file in Genymotion Devices?

Comment: To update Google Play Services, just try to update Google Play Games then it will ask you to update Google Play Services directly through the store. Then you need to reboot *one more time, we're gonna celebrate !* Oh yeah, all right B-)

Comment: Maybe it's the new version on GenyMotion, but It keeps crashing when I try to sign in with my Google Account to the Play Store on 5.0+. I've tried about at least 4 different gapps already and same result.

Comment: I've followed the steps and managed to install Google Play successfully, however Chrome wouldn't start it just crashes giving me only a pop up where I can send a report or click ok. Has anyone encountered a similar situation? I've tried to uninstall chrome and install it again but without any luck.

Comment: For me the device just gets stuck in a loop starting up, does 'optimising  apps', then resets.

Comment: Thanks it worked. but now I am getting player.exe has stopped working.please help

Comment: I had it working without the adb reboots, just had to restart device once after i finished with the file transfers.

Comment: If the phone doesn't give you any response when dragging the *.signed file. Pay attention to the comment of @MichalGallovic. Go to that gist and download the correct archive.

Comment: Good Answer :) But google + irritates a lot by showing error "GOOGLE PLUS HAS STOPPED". I updated and ready to use with error resolved. I did for nexus 5 emulator

Comment: Still works, it's super annoying but don't worry. This method works.

Comment: replace filetrip.net link with some link from "mirros" - filetrip.net sucks

Comment: Does anyone know of a mirror that appears more likely to install the legit "ARM Translation Installer v1.1" than some malware? I'd rather not touch filtrip.netbutseemsmorelikemalware with a ten foot pole.

Comment: Most of these mirrors also appear compromised by varying maliciousnesses of malware: http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/0ZIO8PME/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip_links *UPDATE*: There's an attached file at the bottom of this post that appears more legit than most: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Comment: Play service for For version 6.0.0 :- http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2016/04/installing-gapps-in-visual-studio.html

Comment: @PeterRaeves instead of `adb reboot` do `"C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools\adb" reboot`

Comment: Do I have to choose the gapps platform depending on my pc or does 'platform' refer to the android device I'm running?

Comment: For Nexus 6P I had luck with the instructions linked by @HitCat. Here's another reputable looking resource: https://z3ntu.github.io/2015/12/10/play-services-with-genymotion.html

Comment: Use adb reboot shell instead.

Comment: ARM Translation Installer v1.1 link is dead

Comment: ARM Translation is no longer required when using OpenGApps.

Comment: ARM Translation available under this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdye2pobix70gqw/%5BTechBae.com%5DGenymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip?dl=0

Comment: For me, this gapps I got from here working fine rather than the official website https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145

Answer (score 292):

The latest version of Genymotion (2.10.0 onwards) now allows you to install GApps from the emulator toolbar:

[image]

Click the GApps button the toolbar

[image]

Accept the Terms and Conditions

[image]

Your download of google apps will then begin

Once the download is complete simply restart the virtual device!

Comment: This should be voted to the top.In addition to following this step, it is also recommended to install Google Maps.

Comment: I just get "failed to download" and it stops. Tried many times. The virtual device has working network connection though because I can open the android webview browser app and do a search on google. I used the Genymotion Android 7.0 default phone device, on the first page of the list of virtual devices.

Comment: this worked for me this should be the answer. it always good to scroll down to check other answers

Comment: Does not work for API 16. Returning a dialog with the following: "Open GApps are not available for Android 4.1.1."

Comment: this should be the accepted answer right now!. none of the other methods worked for me... Thanks Open GApps team!!

Comment: Aargh! This should be on the top. Wasted so much time following the old methods.

Comment: @dodgy_coder I got the same error. After about an hour of troubleshooting, I realized there was a new version of genymotion to download. New version's only release notes was a "Fix for Open GApps widget download error" (facepalm). This solution works fine now. Hope that helps!

Comment: how to open GApps from the emulator toolbar: ?

Comment: Worked for us on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: For those looking for the "Emulator Toolbar", for me, on the Android simulator there is a black sidebar on the right side that has an "Open GApps" button at the top. Hope this helps!

Comment: @vikramvi don't know if you managed to solve this but the GApps icon looks like the picture displayed in the beginning of this post. It's located at the top right corner.

Answer (score 54):

You could do this simply by:

1. Download the ARM Translation Installer v1.1(ARMTI)
2. Download the Google Apps for your Android version 4.4, 4.3, 4.2, or
   4.1 for instance
3. Drag and drop the ARMTI to the HomeScreen of your emulator, and
   confirm all
4. Reboot your emulator
5. Drag & Drop the correct Google App version to your HomeScreen
6. Reboot your emulator
7. JOB DONE.

**NOTE:** you can find the right GApp version here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Comment: I got only gmail and hangout app in my genymotion.

Comment: Play service for version 6.0.0:- http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2016/04/installing-gapps-in-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 50):

I tried almost all of the above options, but was not able to install google play services, however just found from [the faq section of genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#google-play-services) that the only way to access google play services is to use the packages provided by OpenGapps.

I tried and this worked:

1. Visit opengapps.org
2. Select x86 as platform
3. Choose the Android version corresponding to your virtual device
4. Select nano as variant
5. Download the zip file
6. Drag & Drop the zip installer in new Genymotion virtual device (2.7.2 and above only)
7. Follow the pop-up instructions

Comment: This works, and is now the official recommended way according to Genymotion - see comment here https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145#gistcomment-1894019 for example. I got this working on a Nexus 5 image running API23 using the x86 nano package

Comment: THIS is the one and only correct and solid solution to this nonsense!  "ARM Translation Installer" is NOT needed. Please up vote this answer to top.

Comment: After wasting hours following now outdated suggestions for changing Geny to ARM, this solution appears to be working.  Tested on 5.0.  Just be sure the gapps version number matches the Geny Android version.

Comment: I had to use an older version (open_gapps-x86-6.0-nano-20170103.zip). The current OpenGApps (open_gapps-x86-6.0-nano-20170205.zip) would hang when flashing.

Comment: Thumbs Up bro! Perfect

Answer (score 23):

For Android 6.0 at least, the ARM Translation thing is apparently unnecessary.

Just grab an x86 + Android 6.0 package (nano is fine) from [OpenGApps](http://opengapps.org/) and install by dragging-and-dropping and telling it to flash.

It seems the ARM translation thing was previously required, before the x86 package was available. You might still need the ARM translation if you want to install ARM-only apps though.

Comment: After 10 years of searching... this finally worked!!!! Using android ``6.0.0``(API 23). Before this I was using endless variations similar to the accepted answer with 800+ votes up. Before this opening the Play Store was stuck on loading. Versions used - ``Ubuntu 14.04``, ``virtualbox 4.3.36``, ``genymotion 2.8.0`` Genymotion emulator - "Google Nexus 6, 6.0.0 API 23"

Comment: Thanks anon. Works perfectly on Mac GM 2.8.0 Android 6.0

Answer (score 16):

#### For Genymotion "Lollipop Preview - Nexus 5" virtual device

- Same steps mentioned in @KingyBobo and @anp8850 answers, but:
- Download the correct GApps for Android 5.0:
  Google Apps for Android 5.0 (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001614559 - gapps-lp-20141109-signed.zip)

**More GApps [here](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145)**

Note that Google+ shows lot of errors before updated.

Answer (score 15):

Now [Gapps](http://opengapps.org/) provide way to install gapps package thorough apk.

Download APK and installation instruction from below link:

http://opengapps.org/app/

You can download current APK from below link:

Play store link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opengapps.app

Current version Website Link (7/22/2017):
http://opengapps.org/app/opengapps-app-v16.apk

[image]

Comment: Wow, this seems a lot more easier than other options. Thanks

Comment: this answer is very out of date and the link is broken

Comment: Yes, play store link is broken. It may removed by gapps developer. You can download gapps apk from direct apk link also.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

As of verison 2.10, Genymotion can be [installed](https://www.genymotion.com/blog/2-10-open-gapps-widget/) using the toolbar in your emulator. Simply look for the *Open GAPPS* button.

Answer (score 14):

With adb, you can install GApps and ARM Support zips without a drag & drop.
[emuking from XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=50166609) has instructions for it:

> I used 4.2.2, which is acceptable for my testing purposes. I then extracted both zip's "/system/..." folders to a folder on my desktop.
>   In cmd prompt I used the following commands (step 1 is optional and for verification that adb is working):

1. adb devices
2. adb remount
3. adb push "C:\Users\John\Desktop\GenyF_cked\system" /system

You'll have to change the folder name in "adb push" line to where you actually extracted both zip files. After doing it, I recommend you to "adb reboot" the device.

Comment: Having tried this, I get error signing in when I try to run setup and signin with my google id. In logcat it prints java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto.

What I did was:
mkdir system
unzip -d system/ open_gapps-x86-4.4-nano-20151224.zip
adb push system /system

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 13):

1. Download [ARM Translation v1.1](http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv) and flash it by dragging and dropping over the emulator. Then reboot the emulator.
2. Go to [Open GApps](http://opengapps.org), select x86 architecture, Android version of your emulator and variant (nano is enough, other applications can be installed from Play Store) and download zip archive. Drag and drop this archive to the emulator and flash it. Reboot the emulator.

Comment: I think that this method is no longer working - it's impossible to flash newest GApps packages (at least for now). More info here: https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/issues/135

Comment: this solution work for my Android `6.0.0` version. Using the nano, make it succeed for me, I try stock and even pico, nothing works. Thank you

Comment: Genymotion 2.7.2 over Windows 10   +  Open GApps x86-5.1-nano + Emulator for Nexus 9 Android 5.1.0 API 22    ......  Are now WORKING!!!

Comment: plus 1 for including the x86 architecture tip

Comment: the x86_64 did not work for me but x86 did even though I have a 64 bit cpu, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 11):

Drag and Drop did not work on my system...

I found a [blogpost](http://blog.tomaslinhart.com/how-to-install-google-apps-in-genymotion/) which describes how you install it with adb:

```
adb push Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip /sdcard/Download/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip

adb push gapps-jb-yyyymmdd-signed.zip /sdcard/Download/gapps.zip

adb shell flash-archive.sh /sdcard/Download/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip

adb reboot

adb shell flash-archive.sh /sdcard/Download/gapps.zip

adb reboot
```

Answer (score 7):

### 3 steps to download the Google Play services *Using Genymotion emulator*

**1. click the right bottom arrow in the toolbar**
[image]

**2. Downloading Bar**

[image]

**3. Needs to restart**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is an Open GAPPS button in the top right corner of the genymotion. Click on it you can directly install Gapps from genymotion.

Answer (score 3):

For Genymotion 2.12.2 you can find GApps added in all their virtual devices. Run any virtual device by Genymotion and then you can find on the top right corner which says Open GApps. Press it and it will automatically install GApps.

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGPHa.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Following the steps in the accepted answer didn't work for me. I followed the steps in [this guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support) with an image running 5.0.0, and it got the job done. It's a step-wise process just like the accepted answer for adding `Google Play` support to genymotion images.

The most important differences are that in the guide I linked to, they mention that installing `Google Play Services` on images running higher than 5.0.0 may not work, and they say to change the `ADB tool connection settings` in the `Genymotion` desktop application's settings window to: `Use custom Android SDK tools`. Also, the `gapps` zips seem to be different.

The guide also uses GIFs to illustrate the steps in the process, so it leaves much less room for doubt.

[Link to `gapps` zip for Android 5.0 used in the guide](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001614559) -- requires Genymotion 2.4.0+

[Link to ARM Translation Installer v1.1 used in the guide](http://www14.zippyshare.com/v/44278764/file.html) -- this is provided for convenience. it doesn't seem any different than the one provided in the accepted answer at first glance

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of genymotion and after creating a device click on Open GAPP in device right side.

That work for me

Answer (score 0):

Tried to download Gapps app and install it on Genymotion, but realized that its already included within the emulator itself

https://www.genymotion.com/blog/2-10-open-gapps-widget/