# Genymotion virtual device and Genymotion software do not match

Tags: android, genymotion

I want to open camera in "Nexus One - 4.1.1 - with Google Apps"

I deleted the device and Add it again but it' still old version.

How to get the newer version of device?

**EDIT**

You can delete the folder manually and download the device again.

Comment: I don't understand your question, first how is it related to a camera? second, "with Google Apps" no longer exists in Genymotion, so you are either using an old version, or you are not logging into their service, last, what do you mean "newer version" you mean version 4.3? or new instance (new image)?

Comment: @nrathaus Yes, I'm using the older version and I upgraded it, now I can't see any device with the Google apis.. In newer version we can use webcam as device camera which is not supported in older version.. Is there any way to use google api in newer version?

Comment: I tried this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-service-in-the-genymotion-ubuntu-13-04-currently-i#) but not succeed..

Comment: Yes, I am able to use Google API in newer version of genymotion I actually used that exact link you gave and it works. What happens to you that made you come to the conclusion it doesn't work?

Comment: I follow the steps, but I'm not able to see google apis in device, when I drag & drop second zip it says successfully copied to sd card and then I restarted device, but not able to see any difference..

Comment: You don't see the Google Play appear?

Comment: No, I can't see any Google apps..

Comment: You installed the `gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip` file?

Comment: I installed this gapps-jb-20130813-signed

Comment: Ok, and Google Play doesn't appear in your list of apps?

Comment: No, is there any difference between gapps-jb-20130811/12/13 -signed.zip ?

Comment: Not sure, I don't think so, are you running on a 64bit environment? do you have a VTx CPU? I had issues running it on "old" CPU systems/operating system

Comment: Yes, I'm using 64-bit Windows 7. Don't know about VTx CPU.

Comment: When you run VirtualBox does it allow you to enable VTx? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vt-x#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29

Comment: In Oracle VirtualBox I can see Under System: Acceleration: VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Paging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you have updated to the latest GenyMotion Version to 2.10 from 2.02...

1. Open GenyMotion
2. Go to the List of your 2.02 Devices
3. Left click the item and then right click on the menu to **Delete all your 2.02 Virtual Devices
4. Click the Add button at the top to add a New Device. Log into your account
5. Select the device you want. You can only select one device at a time
6. Click the Next button. Notice the Version number says - 2.10. There is other info about the device here.
7. Your device will start downloading to your GenyMotion Folder on the Drive **C.
8. After you download it, double click it to open up the Virtual Device like you normally would.
9. Repeat for other device you want

`C:\%Users%\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed`

Comment: I've manually deleted .Genymbile folder and re-download devices. Thanks for the information.