# Install genymotion on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-emulator, genymotion

Following the [link](http://www.enqlu.com/2014/03/how-to-install-genymotion-android-emulator-on-ubuntu-or-linux-mint.html) steps with:

`genymotion 2.2.2` on `ubuntu 14.04 x64` with `samsung Galaxy s4/s5 4.4.2`

has problem after installation of

`Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip` and `gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip`.

When I reboot device it shows two errors:

"`Unfortunately, Google play services has stopped`"

and

"`Unfortunately, the process com.google.process.gapps has stopped`".

Any ideas how to workaround this problem ?

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: Yup, it works. Just follow the installation of 2.0+ version and install. AFAIK, It required to install virtualbox, geanymotion, 2x packages with gapps and abi_interface. Rather simple. What I used to do other way, was to restart genymotion emulator via adb commandline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su)

Answer (score 2):

First you have to install genymotion plugin, you can find it at android studio settings-plugins-browse
Do it this way:

1. Open **Terminal**
2. **Copy** and **paste** **bin** file of **genymotion** in **home directory**
3. Type **chmod +x genymotion-2.5.2_x64.bin**
4. Type **./genymotion-2.5.2_x64.bin**
5. Press **Y**

**Done**

Answer (score 0):

The file gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip seems to be buggy. I downloaded the more recent from:

http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps#gappsCM11

And now it seems to be working fine after play store update.