# Android device not showing in Google play on Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion, google-play, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed the free version of [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) on ubuntu 14.04. After that I installed all google apps according to [How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-service-in-the-genymotion-ubuntu-13-04-currently-i)

Now I have an app that I want to install, which keeps saying "You don't have any devices". So when I go to my [Google Play store settings](https://play.google.com/settings), there is indeed no device listed. So how do I get the device there?

Comment: Did you sign in on the device with your usual gmail/google+ account?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk What do you mean by 'usual'? It's the first time I use an android device, but I used my regular gmail address. I can see my google+ contacts. Also when I deleted all data from the google store app and vink or unvink "Keep me up to date with news and offers from Google Play.", it changes just fine at play.google.com/settings, so it seems to sync correctly. I tried to setup two different devices through genymotion and downloaded an app on one device, and it showed up under 'myapps' on the other device, so it stores this information, just not my actual devices.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Except for Google+. That seems to crash all the time. Not sure if this is related to the device not showing up