# How to install other apps like Twitter and Facebook on Genymotion

Tags: java, android, genymotion

I was wondering if was possible to install other apps like Twitter and Facebook on Genymotion. If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I think that more comfortable solution is install Google Play Store.

[How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su) this can help you

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged here at Stack Overflow.  Instead, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a virtual machine "**genymotion**" having Google Play Services and when the virtual machine starts and will have the "Play Store" and download any application.

Comment: i have done that and i installed facebook and twitter apps on it but the problem here is that i cannot run an activity i created which involves them on the virtual device. Ex, i developed an activity and integrated twitter with it but when i run it, all i get is "No apps installed to open this activity". i have already rebooted the virtual device,updated the play store apps but same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you have well put the names of the packages in the Intent?

Comment: Pless check correct answer if i help you of original post.

Comment: Sorry for not responding for a longtime. i haven't been online for a while. now, how do i do that?@TeRRo

Comment: You have to download one virtual machine with Google Play. In the list the virtual machine of genymotion you have some virtual machine with Google Play.

Comment: @Andrecon You can follow this tutorial http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/