# Install Google Play Services to Genymotion Problems

Tags: android, google-play-services, genymotion

[i followed this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su)
, after rebooting genymotion arm , and drop gapps-kk-20140105-signed.zip to my emulator and the problem :

### Oops , Something went wrong when flashing

and now my emulator always appears a toast "Google play services has stopped working now !" everytime it occurs a activity !

Then i got it , i put a wrong GApps to it . i deleted the error emulator , and add a new one by genymotion. But now i CAN NOT drag and drop file to the emulator anymore . why is it , or you can show me another way to install google play services to genymotion emulator !
Please help me , thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you perhaps post a Genymotion's log? Be sure to have the correct GApps to the target Genymotion VM.

Comment: i got it , i put a wrong GApps to it  . Now i deleted the error emulator , and add a new one . But now i cant drag and drop file to the emulator anymore . why is it , or you can show me another way to install google play services to genymotion emulator !

Comment: Try to add GApps based on the version in android emulator . After installing GApps to the genymotion restart the emulator and update GApps using internet . It will work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I used the emulator to update the google play apps and it seems to be working fine now.