# SauceLab - Appium integration for Android - Get Google Play Services

Tags: appium, saucelabs

I have integrated Appium with SauceLab. I am able to run the app on Android Emulator using SauceLab.
I am stuck at this dialog "GET GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES", as my app requires Play Services. I am aware Android Emulator does not come with Google Play services. Is there any solution or can I use other emulators which have play services pre-installed?

My appium.txt looks like this

```
[caps]
appium-version = "1.1.0"
platformName = "Android"
platformVersion = "4.4"
deviceName = "Android Emulator"
app = "/Users/jitendra/Desktop/Appium/TSU/tsu_v1.0.2_integration.apk"
appWaitActivity = "com.evac.tsu.activities.start.LoginActivity"
name = "TSU Android Automate Testing"

[appium_lib]
debug = true
wait = 120
export_session = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SauceLabs currently supports this feature. You may be forced to manually test until SauceLabs has a solution.

In the past when I have tested Android apps, there were custom emulators that came bundled with Google play services - AndroVM (now [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)) for manual testing. You can [setup play services on Genymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su) VM (although I believe this will have to be done for each configuration).

The part I never tried before is using Appium but [this blog](http://dbwest.github.io/blog/2013/09/16/appium-for-ios-and-android-automated-testing/) highlights how to setup Appium to work with Genymotion.