# Lollipop device is not opening in genymotion

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, genymotion, nexus-7, android-virtual-device

I am using  `Android studio 1.0.1`. Using `Genymotion + virtual box (2.3.1)`.I have downloaded `nexus 4` (Android Lollipop) device. Whenever i am trying to open the device , it comes on the screen, shows "android" and stay in the same position. It doesn't open ever. I have tried with `nexus 7` and even with a Custom device. It is happening only for "Lollipop" devices, others devices like KitKat is running very good.

Answer (score 1):

Download

```
Virtual Devices Google Nexus 5 - 5.0.0 API21 - 1080x1920
```

Comment: No result :( 
It's remaining the same :(

Comment: Check ur SDK Manager Android 5.0.1 (API21)

Comment: files related tv,wear and google API's are not installed. Others are installed. Should i install google APIs?

Comment: Bro , i have installed everything but nothing is happening :(

Answer (score 1):

Update Genymotion and VirtualBox to the latest version then delete and reinstall Android 5.0.1 API 21 on your android SDK Manager. This work for me.

I have installed **Google Nexus 7 - 5.0.0 API 21 - 800x1280**

if you have problem with gapps and drag & drop on Genymotion, check this answer [install GApps and ARM Support zips without a drag & drop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26081335/2576595)

If you follow all the steps, should work

Answer (score 0):

Update your gennymotion and Search for devices with API 21. I'm using Nexus 6 having Lollipop. There is no issue with it. Give a try to Nexus 6

Comment: I have downloaded the available upgraded version of genymotion that includes virtualbox. Does it has any relation with my laptop? I am using a 64-bit , i-3 processor.

Comment: I'm also using 64-bit. No it doesn't have any issues with your laptop.

Comment: Nexus 6, 10 , even each and every devices given in suggestion has been tried , But nothing is happening :( Please ... I need help :(

Comment: I think you should reinstall Gennymotion completely . or you can email to gennymotion support team

Comment: I have reinstalled Genymotion completely just a few hours ago. Yeah um too thinking about email :(

Comment: Yea mail them , that will be the best option. Best of luck.

Comment: I confirm, email us! https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/support#contact

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Once I updated to Genymotion 2.3.1 Lollipop devices would not boot anymore (android logo -> black screen).

**Solution**

I solved this issue by clearing the Genymotion cache:

```
Genymotion -> Settings -> Misc -> Clear cache
```

After clearing the cache I added a new Nexus 5 (API 21) emulator and it booted fine.

**Notes:**

- I did not have this issue with Genymotion 2.3.0
- Removing the Nexus 5 emulator and adding it back again did not solve the issue.