# How to run Google Map API V2 on genymotion

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, genymotion

I have implemented an android application with Google Map, using v2 Version . i tested the app on a real device . it is working fine , but i want to test it on genymotion also . How can i do that ?

Comment: Go from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the directions posted in this forum: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952%5d

**Long Story Short**
Genymotion emulators are missing a set of libraries that real devices have. For example to many features nowadays (such as google maps api related features) you need to have the google-play libraries. Same rule applies for all other third party apis e.g. Facebook SDK.
 Some people in the forum (link above) have created such libraries that you install on your Genymotion emulator simply by drag&drop.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

you have to download gapps from below link and drag and drop in emulator.
https://basketbuild.com/gapps

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you need to download the google apps and drag and drop the downloaded zip onto your emulator.  Perhaps, the best place to download from is the from the [opengapps.org](http://opengapps.org/) project.  Plenty of options there too.

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion emulators are missing a set of libraries that real devices have. For example to many features nowadays (such as google maps api related features) you need to have the google-play libraries. Same rule applies for all other third party apis e.g. Facebook SDK. Some people in the forum (link above) have created such libraries that you install on your Genymotion emulator simply by drag&drop.