# Implementing Interstitial Ad; Google Play out of date. Update emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, ads, interstitial

Pretty much what the title says. I'm trying to implement the ads, and it just won't show up. The logcat says the ad is even loading, it just won't show on the screen. I think I have everything downloaded in the sdk manager, gradle play services is for 7.0.0, emulator has x86 google APIs running for it- it might be the emulator that's off in some other way that needs updating?...I just don't know how to fix the emulator if that's the problem. Below is the error that comes across.

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7095000 but found 6774470
```

Comment: what is the android version on emulator?

Comment: 5.1.1 API 22 Lollipop

Answer (score 0):

You have to update `Google Play Services` on the device. Use this code to prompt user that he needs to update the app.

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable( getApplicationContext() );
if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    //alarm to go and install Google Play Services
}else if(status == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED){
   Toast.makeText(context,"please udpate your google play service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I'll throw this into the java for other users. But, and this may be a very dumb questoins, for my own my emulator how do I update it on my emulator? I guess I'll try what this video says later today (at work currently): youtube.com/watch?v=vVFL87iv3-s

Comment: you just go to Play Market and straightly click `update` instead of install. Or as in video, same effect :)

Comment: I can't update the emulator via google play. When I sign into google play it tries to update my personal cell phone I have synced with it. I think I'm just going to fiddle around with the emulator some more, and say screw it and install all SDK options like the wearables APIs ones too. Funny thing is, I downloaded an interstitial example from github and it works fine...

Comment: hm... about updating I'm really surprised. Just few weeks ago I faced similar and I updated on Genimotion emulator...

Comment: I've just been using the AVD emulators you make in android studio. Make I'll go ahead and try Genimotion at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is the following:

1) install Genimotion 
 a)use this, https://www.genymotion.com/ it's pretty straight forward
 b) further setup instructions: http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/22/android-studio-plus-genymotion-emulator/

2) Add google play services to Genimotion. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su) does a great job explaining.