# About Genymotion and Google APIs?

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

When creating an AVD, I need to select Google APIs for Target to run an application with  Google Map.

How about Genymotion?

Do I also need to set something when adding a new Genymotion virtual device?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a simple genymotion virtual device and follow the below link for further instructions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20137324/3541465