# React native TypeError: Network request failed with fetch()

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fetch-api

I'm using React native for developing an android application. With this fetch request I'm getting the error `TypeError: network request failed`:

```
fetch('https://pixabay.com/api/?key=MY_KEY&q='+ this.props.jsondata.city.name +'&lang=en&image_type=photo&orientation=horizontal&category=travel&safesearch=true')
        .then(response => {
            console.dir(response);
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(data.statusText);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json.hits[0].largeImageURL)
            this.setState(() => {
                return {backImage: json.hits[0].largeImageURL};
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Unable to search image! ' + err);
        });
```

I've already searched online but this problem appears only with localhost addresses or http, that is not my case. The request is inside the `componentDidMount()` function. I've made a similar request (with the same structure) in an another place of the application but there is no error there. I'm using a real android device to testing the app with the react-native app compiled in android native code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
2. Delete all debug folder from your android folder.

Comment: well after wasting 1-2 hrs finally, this solution helped!!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the main reason for the error is [emulator SSL certificate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126601/android-ssl-problems-in-android-studio-emulator-works-fine-on-phone).
To solve the issue you may use a real device for testing your app or you may set up a persistent Certificate Authority (CA).

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked since everywhere folks were referring to "localhost", which i was not using i found a solution that worked for me, for which you need to add the required host in the following file
`android/app/src/debug/res/xml/react_native_config.xml`.
This is my how my xml looks now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.3.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">facebook.github.io</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

After which my below fetch request started working:

```
fetch('http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
});
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but one thing: you are calling HTTP and not HTTPS endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

In general, this error occurs when your network is not secure (for example, if you use an http connection instead of https).

If you check the [official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.65/network), you will find the warning below.

> On Android, as of API Level 28, clear text traffic is also blocked by default. This behaviour can be overridden by setting [android:usesCleartextTraffic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) in the app manifest file.

So you can try adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the application declaration of your AndroidManifest.xml file usually located at `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

If this doesn't work as in my case, you can check if there is an `android:networkSecurityConfig` declaration in your manifest. If there is, go to the location of the file (`"@xml/network_security_config"` in my case) and add your custom domain that you want to trust.
Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <!-- add your domain like below -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.8.103</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">pixabay.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try verifying if the device has internet connection before making the http request.
React Native has a module to verify that: [Netinfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo).

```
import { NetInfo } from 'react-native';

             ... your component code

checkInternetConnection = () => {

    return NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then((isConnected) => {
        return isConnected;
      });

  };
```