# Installing Google Play in GenyMotion by default when creating a device (takes time to do it when creating multiple devices)

Tags: android, genymotion

I know how to install Google Play Services on Genymotion devices with the Arm Translation Zip and the other zip. But is there anyway to install them by default when I create the virtual device ?

or some other `adb` commands to install it in batch (ie from Device Named '1' to device named '15'. I am naming the device with numbers. So it can make the installation easier.. and I could update the Google Play Services myself in Play Store (sadly, i don't think there are other ways to update it.)

Answer (score 2):

Genymotion doesn't provide Google Apps. To install Google Apps:

1. Upgrade Genymotion and VirtualBox to the latest version.
2. Download two zip files:

    - [**ARM Translation Installer v1.1**](http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv)

    - **Google Apps for your Android version**: [2.3.7 - 4.4.4](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps) or [5.0](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001614559)
3. Open Genymotion emulator and go to home screen then drag and drop the first file **Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip** over the emulator. A dialog will appear and show as file transfer in progress, then another dialog will appear and ask that do you want to flash it on the emulator. Click OK and reboot the device by running `adb reboot`.
4. Drag and drop the second file **gapps-*-signed.zip** and repeat the same steps as above. Run `adb reboot` and, once rebooted, Google Apps will be in the emulator.
5. **At this point 'Google Apps Services' will crash frequently** with the following message `google play services has stopped working`. Open Google Play. After providing your account details, open Google Play and update your installed Google Apps. This seems to make Google Play realize you have an old Google Play Services and will ask you to update (in my case, **updating Google Hangouts required a new version of Google Play Services**). I've also heard that simply waiting will also prompt you to update. The 'Google Play Services' app doesn't seem to appear otherwise - you can't search for it. You should then see an offer to update Google Play Services. Once the new Google Play Services is installed you will now have stable, working access to Google Play

Taken from [How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su)

Comment: Hey, I already mentioned that I know this method. I am asking for something a but more automated to do it on many devices

Comment: oops sorry, i had not read that, you can try adb sideload, but i dont think the process is automated