# How to install Google Play Services on 6.0 Genymotion device?

Tags: java, android, genymotion

How to install Google Play Services on 6.0 Genymotion device?

For other versions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su) answer works, but not for 6.0

**EDIT**:

I've tried to use 6.0 Gapps from [this](http://www.gadgetraid.com/2015/10/download-google-gapps-for-android-6-0-marshmallow-roms/) source, but all of them failed to flash the emulator.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Ivan,
I found the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145) and followed the steps from the user @sinistance and it worked for me using the Nexus 5X Preview API 23.

To simplify this is the answer:

> > what image did you use? i'm using the preview nexus 5x image. here is the steps:
> >
> > 1. flash Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip then restart.
> > 2. flash gapps-L-4-21-15.zip.
> > 3. sign in into your google account.
> > 4. flash benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip then restart.
> >
> > that's all

You can find all the files in the link above!
I hope it works for you!

Regards

Comment: Worked for me. I just updated play store apps after step 3. I think we do not need step 4.

Comment: Ok. On updating google play services, after step 3, I was still getting message that Google Play services has stopped. So I performed step 4 and everything seems fine now.

Comment: Exactly, you can skip step 4, even you can skip "restart" part of step 1, after that step 3 it's obvious and shouldn't be added as step. Step 4 causes "Play Services has stopped" message.

Comment: Great! Worked. Thanks.

Comment: this didn't work for me, as I'm already using "stable" 6.0 and not the preview. Just installing gapps-L will kind of work, but you won't get any Maps on apps.

Comment: dead link for 6.0 MarshMallow

Comment: Adding google account to the play services not working properly. did anyone faced this.?

Comment: update google play services and then flash benzo zip file.

Comment: Works perfectly for Samsung Galaxy S6 image as well. @RaguSwaminathan play services crashed during sign in, but second attempt worked just fine

Answer (score 9):

Since Genymotion 2.7.2 and above follow these steps.

https://www.genymotion.com/faq/#google-play-services

1. Visit opengapps.org
2. Select x86 as platform
3. Choose the Android version corresponding to your virtual device
4. Select nano as variant
5. Drag & Drop the zip installer in new Genymotion virtual device
6. Follow the pop-up instructions

Answer (score 8):

On Samsung Galaxy S6 - 6.0.0 - 1440x2560:

- Flash Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1
- Flash open_gapps-x86-6.0-pico-20160524.zip

Please give it a try.

Comment: https://github.com/opengapps/x86/releases  find the gapps here.

Comment: work like a charm, used https://github.com/opengapps/x86/releases/download/20160714/open_gapps-x86-6.0-micro-20160714.zip with any 6.0.0 genymotion devices.

Note: to be safe, use turn off or adb restart command, instead of close button on the genymotion window.

Answer (score 4):

If Google Play Services on Android 6.0 crash everytime, you can try do  the same things in this sequence. Maybe it will work.

Here is what I did:

1. Install a latest Genymotion (version 2.6.0 in my case). Make sure
   the previous old (preview) Android 6.0 images are removed(Genymotion
   -> Settings -> Misc -> Clear cache).
2. Add a new virtualdevice, select Google Nexus 5X and Android 6.0
   image. It should download a new image from Genymotion website.Start
   created Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920 virtual device.
3. Flash Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip (drag&drop the zip file to
   virtual device window) and then restart the virtual device.
4. Flash gapps-L-4-21-15.zip and restart the virtual device again. Now
   add Google account in the virtual device via Settings -> Accounts ->
   Add account. Do not start Google Play! Ignore any crashes in sign in
   process.
5. Flash benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip and restart the
   virtual device. Open Google Play in virtual device,update all
   installed applications.
6. Start Google Now with long touch on home button to force dialog with
   request to update Google Play Services. Update Google Play Services.
   Now the device is prepared with working Google Play and Google Play
   Services.

[Genymotion android 6.0 with Google play service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuaCg.png)

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked just to install a package (in my case the full) for x86 and Android Version 6.0 from http://opengapps.org/ by dragging the downloaded zip-file to the machine. A restart was suggested and done

Maybe some Apps won't work but you don't have to do anything else.
I hope I could help you with that answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It helped me to install GApps for emulated Android 5.1.0 (pico with 50 MB was enough in my case :)

Answer (score 0):

For enable Google play service in genymotion  marshmallow version

Download and  install  Install ARM Translation from  here : http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv
After installation  reboot your device (Just  close and  restart )

After restart Download the gapps/5.1/gapps-L-4-21-15.zip flash from : 
http://mirror31.downloadandroidrom.com/download/gapps/5.1/gapps-L-4-21-15.zip?token=432826691

After installation .  reboot  the device and  update yourgoogle play service and google.

Comment: this is for 5.1, not 6

Answer (score -1):

For enable Google play service in genymotion, as per answer you mentioned in your question you need ARM and Gapps.

So, Download gapps for Android Marshmallow from [here](http://www.gadgetraid.com/2015/10/download-google-gapps-for-android-6-0-marshmallow-roms/) and follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su).

Comment: I've tried couple of Gapps versions but they failed to flash. Did you manage to flash your 6.0 Genymotion with particular Gapps build?

Comment: I did not try for that let me check for 6.0 Genymotion with gapps I mentioned. if I will get any appropriate solution I will update my answer.

Comment: thanks. I've tried all Gapps version from the link above, but none of them worked.

Comment: Same here but i seen there image for 6.0 is still in Preview version so maybe its under construction or after some time available for use.