# Installing google play services in genymotion, stuck with checking info

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, genymotion

I was trying to install google play services in genymotion. Everything went ok but after launching google play, it's just showing ***Checking info..*** from 2 hours.
[EmuatorStuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiZLq.png)

I followed instructions from here

[How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su)

My device configurations are as follows:

Google Nexus 5-5.1.0- API22 -1080*1920

HDPI_miniGAPPS-5...150120-signed.zip

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue regarding Genymotion and Android. See [Setup Google Play Services](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support#setup-google-play-services). Android 5 devices requires Genymotion 2.4.0+ in order to run without problems. I recommend that you check your Genymotion version. You may also follow the instructions [Installing Genymotion](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support#installing-genymotion).

Hope it works!

Comment: my genymotioin version is 2.5.2