# Google Play real-time multiplayer does not work on a Genymotion virtual device

Tags: android, genymotion, multiplayer

I have an Android app with Google Play Achievements and Leaderboards Services.
I want to add Real-time Multiplayer.
So I have downloaded  ButtonClicker2000 example from [Github](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) and link it to an my existing game service

This app works fine on physical devices, but on Genymotion device attempt to create Room returns Status code 7000 in callback [onRoomCreated](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomUpdateListener).

```
// Called when room has been created
@Override
public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRoomCreated(" + statusCode + ", " + room + ")");
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        Log.e(TAG, "*** Error: onRoomCreated, status " + statusCode);
        showGameError();
        return;
    }

   // save room ID so we can leave cleanly before the game starts.
    mRoomId = room.getRoomId();

    // show the waiting room UI
    showWaitingRoom(room);
}
```

Status code 7000 value is:
STATUS_REAL_TIME_CONNECTION_FAILED - Failed to initialize the network connection for a real-time room.

Turning On/Off Real-time multiplayer switch on Developer Console does not change result.

I don't shure multiplayer can work on Genymotion. I don't found any explicit confirmation on stackoverflow.

Genymotion version 2.6.0 Revision 20151127-3674435
Device: Google Nexus S 4.1.1
Google Play services version: 8.4.89 (2428711-070)
GApps: gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip

If anyone run real-time multiplayer on Genymotion please answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am running my multiplayer game on genymotion devices. I am using the same specs as you. Unfortunately I receive sometimes a error (status code 4, today first time status code 7000). However, most times it works. I followed this tutorial: [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20137324/4565322).
Did you changed the code, like onstart(), .connect or .create call?

Comment: The good news that it works. I did not change anything in the example code.
Did you changed anything (for example the network settings)?

Comment: No, i didn't changed any network settings. I am using custom phone with API 16. Don't forget to connect only devices with different gmail accounts.