# Cannot make react-native-maps to work on android

Tags: android, google-maps, reactjs, maps, react-native

I'm trying to create a simple "weather" app using react-native on Android.

I have followed the [installation steps](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md) but I get following errors when I run `react-native run-android`

**JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...**

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-maps'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-maps:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0.
>           Searched in the following locations:
>               file:/home/mihir/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.3.0/play-services-base-8.3.0.pom
>               file:/home/mihir/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.3.0/play-services-base-8.3.0.jar
>               https:// jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.3.0/play-services-base-8.3.0.pom
>               https:// jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.3.0/play-services-base-8.3.0.jar
>               file:/home/mihir/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.3.0/play-services-base-8.3.0.pom
>               file:/home/mihir/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/8.3.0/play-services-base-8.3.0.jar
>           Required by:
>               weather:react-native-maps:unspecified
>   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0.
>           Searched in the following locations:
>               file:/home/mihir/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.pom
>               file:/home/mihir/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.jar
>               https:// jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.pom
>               https:// jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.jar
>               file:/home/mihir/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.pom
>               file:/home/mihir/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.jar
>           Required by:
>               weather:react-native-maps:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 20.584 secs
Could not install the app on the device, rea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install Google Play Services to make react-native-maps work on Android.

Go in a terminal and run `android`. This should open the SDK manager.

If the command `android` is not found, you need to install the SDK tools from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)

Install Google Play Services and Google Repository.

[image]

Rerun `react-native run-android`and it should work if you use a device.

If you use an emulator, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su/20137324#20137324).