# Android Warning: Native component for "AIRMap" does not exist

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have successfully added an Airbnb map in react app.

But when I am adding an Airbnb map view to existing android native application. I am getting always empty map with red border.

I am using RN 0.40 and react-native-maps 0.13.0.

After the **react-native link** commands. Then android always have the Warning:

> **Native component for "AIRMap" does not exist.**
>
> Running application "App" with appParams:
> {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. DEV === true, development-level
> warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF

Here is my MainApplication.java file

```
package punchh.customreactcomponent;

import android.app.Application;

import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
              new MainReactPackage(),
              new MapsPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe update your post with your `Application.java` file?

Comment: @martinarroyo I have posted Application.java file. You can check this out.

Comment: @martinarroyo can you please help on this issue

Comment: Mmm... I was expecting the `getPackages()` not to have the `new MapsPackage()` line, which was likely to be the error, but other than that, I am out of ideas. The problem is that the name 'AIRMap' cannot be found in any of the native modules. The module names are found in the `getName` function, as in here: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapModule.java#L43 I'd suggest you go through the files and check if there is a name mismatch of some sort.

Comment: @martinarroyo There is no name mismatch for AIRMap in MapView.js file. So, how can we identify the problem behind this.

Comment: Mmm... I am not sure. Check that you have followed all the steps in the documentation, try to replicate them in a new clear project and also maybe the example projects included in the repo might be of help.

Comment: Did you succeed finding a solution to this problem? I'm facing the same issue when developing in a simulator with react-native.

Comment: @GarimaMathur Did you find any solution to this issue. I am using react-native-maps(0.13.0) and react-native(0.43.3))

Comment: Ok I fixed it using `react-native start` and closing the app and then running `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was getting that error (and a blank screen) when attempting to run an app on an android simulator. I fixed the issue with applying the next steps:

**1 - Running `react-native link`** then restarted the js server (`react-native start`) and redeployed the app on simulator (react-native run-android)

**2 - Running on a real device or on a simulator based on GoogleApi system image**. If you get a `googleApi not supported message` then add some packages in android studio and create a new device as described in next link:

[My application relies Google play services, which is not supported by your device. contact the manufacturer for assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890714/my-application-relies-google-play-services-which-is-not-supported-by-your-device)

The working configuration for my virtual device:

[image]

**3 - Adding the Google_API_KEY (If you don't have one you'll have to create it) in manifest file (android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml)**:

```
   <!-- make sure it's a child of application -->
   <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="Your Google maps API Key Here"/>
```

- Started the device, restarted js server, redeployed on device
- Everything should have worked but I faced an issue with my google_api_key (an empty yellow map) like in the next picture:
  [image]

so I created and enabled a new one specific for my project here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert

- Restarted JS server, ran `react-native run-android` and it worked:
  [image]

To debug I used `adb logcat` in a separate terminal.

Inspired from:
https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md
and from 
https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/118

If the map still doesn't show you might need some styling. I added a basic one to my component like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import {
    View, StyleSheet
} from 'react-native'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    map: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    },
});

export default class MyMap extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { region } = this.props;

        return (
            <View style ={styles.container}>
                <MapView
                    style={styles.map}
                    region={{
                   latitude: 44.42,
                   longitude: 26.10,
                   latitudeDelta: 0.015,
                   longitudeDelta: 0.0121
                 }}
                >
                </MapView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding MapsPackage to the getPackages method in MainApplication.java file.

no need to add `@Override`

My Code looks like this:

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MapsPackage()
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ITS WORKING

it repeated this failure to recreate successfull working react-native-maps

react - 16.3.1
react-native - 0.55.4
react-native-maps - 0.21.0

**step 1**
i created app like this
$react-native init tank1

**step 2**
I followed installation from [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md)

**step 3**
follow installation from [Moses Lucas post](https://itnext.io/install-react-native-maps-with-gradle-3-on-android-44f91a70a395) ***important***

**step 4**
in MainApplication.java
use below code without `@Override`

```
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
              new MainReactPackage(),
              new MapsPackage()
      );
  }
```

**Note 1**
I had doub't about synatx `@import GoogleMaps;` in `AppDelegete.m` but this too works fine

**Note 2** 
If you had run `react-native link`
please check `settings.gradle` it should not contain duplicate entries

**Note 3**
Do not remove `include ':app'` from  `settings.gradle`