# Error when using Maps in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, google-maps, react-native

I want to use maps in my react native app. So I installed react-native-maps from airbnb, but when I try to build the apps it always shows this error `"Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler."` , I already set up the build gradle, the setting gradle, and the MainApllication. Can anyone help me in here?
**My Build.Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

**My Setting.Gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'MapDemo'
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
include ':app'
```

**My MainApplication.Java**

```
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
 @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
           new MapsPackage()
      );
    }
```

Comment: Just to be sure, have you edited the build.gradlew in the `android/app/build.gradle` ?

Comment: Guyz its gradle version issue , please check this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50777873/1390678)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced a similar issue and found the solution from [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/2152):

Navigate to `node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build.gradle` and then
change `compileOnly` to `provided` and `implementation` to `compile`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of changing the library you can follow this (https://itnext.io/install-react-native-maps-with-gradle-3-on-android-44f91a70a395)

Answer (score 0):

Changing a file in the third-party module you're using is probably not the best solution to most problems.  It seems that this error is caused because the module has been upgraded to use gradle 3, which is incompatible with the gradle 2 version used by default in react native.  There are useful steps to upgrade here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1490