# I can see the buttons but cant see maps getting rendered

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, reactjs, maps, react-native

[image]

This is my index.android.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Navigator,
} from 'react-native';

import SplashPage from './SplashPage';
import MainPage from './MainPage';
import Pager from './Pager';
import App from './App';

class Demo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
          initialRoute={{id: 'SplashPage', name: 'Index'}}
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          configureScene={(route) => {
              if (route.sceneConfig) {
                return route.sceneConfig;
              }
              return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
          }} />
    );
  }
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    const routeId = route.id;
    if (routeId === 'SplashPage') {
      return (
        <SplashPage
          navigator={navigator} />
      );
    }
    if (routeId === 'App') {
      return (
        <App
          navigator={navigator} />
      );
    }
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Demo', () => Demo);
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>
```

I have referred to the following url https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps.I have also resolved the API's issue but still map not getting rendered.
Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: It should tell you in the LogCat what's going wrong. What does it say there?

Comment: where i can see logcat while running react-native apps? i used the command adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V to see the logcat but it shows nothing.

Comment: I'v never used React Native so hopefully someone else can help with that bit.

Comment: Have you tried to add Google Play Services to your Genymotion? here's a SO ticket show how to [install Google Play Services in a Genymotion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys the above code is proper and there is no bug just the issue is that maps don't work on genymotion. To make app running on genymotion follow the link
[How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su/20137324#20137324)
proved to be very helpful. 
The following code  https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps. runs fine on physical device. 
Hope this will be helpful.