# Google Play services out of date. Requires 9256000 but found 9080470

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

Simply just created a new blank GoogleMaps activity, when I go to run the emulator, the emulator displays..

[image: Emulator message]

Heres what I have installed in the SDK manager..

[image: SDK manager]

and here's the latest message I get in the monitor when I try and run the app...

```
06-30 15:46:42.388 2783-2783/jackc.mapslesson W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9256000 but found 9080470
```

In SDK Tools I have it installed

[image: SDK Tools]

and in extras...

[image: extras]

Only fix I have currently found is in the Module grade, where it says...

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

If I change it to...

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```

It then works, why is this? and is there a fix so that it works on 9.2.0?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had same problem and i was trying to solve it whole day. You can do two things:

- As you mentioned, you can downgrade to 9.0.2
- Or you can use Genymotion emulator which is based on VM and install Google Play Services from zip file. Working [GUIDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20137324/3687473). I choose this solution and it works like a charm.

Before I started use Genymotion, I added new [threads](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=sykora.david.private%40gmail.com&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&cells=tiles) to code.google issues tracker.

Answer (score 3):

From after two days of work i got to know how actually it'll work

1.Install a system image without Google API

2.Download the latest Google play [Use this official Google play URL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms)  from here [Convert to apk](https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/)

3.Now install the apk through terminal adb install yourapknamehere
PS : You can find adb here C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Voila run the emulator and check the Google play version Settings->App->Google Play.It'll be the latest one

Comment: In my case, it fails stating "Failure[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]" :(

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I was getting this error while trying to integrate firebase messaging

Answer (score 2):

All I had to do to fix this was get into Google Play with the android device and download/update Google Play services.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing on an emulator, you can use an earlier version on your app build.gradle (unfortunately the emulators don't include the updated version).

You can use this in the app level gradle:

```
"compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'"
```

and and this is the dependency for the Google Services Gradle plugin in the project top-level build.gradle:

```
"classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. However downgrading to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```

did not work for me. However, I was able to update the Android SDK and tools, then my emulators worked just fine using:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
```

[These were the Android SDK and tools that I updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DW2l.png)

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to update your Google Play services in Android Studio.

Go to SDK Manager, and go to tab SDK tools.

There search for Google Play services and update that. This should help.