# No Google Play App in Emulator

Tags: android, flash, google-play-services, genymotion

I have been trying to get Google Play Services into my Genymotion emulator and I followed @arcao's process on the GitHub page where many people talk about this issue:

"
I am confirming that steps from @esantiago1 works!

Here is what I did:

- Install a latest Genymotion (version 2.6.0 in my case).
  Make sure the previous old (preview) Android 6.0 images are removed (Genymotion -> Settings -> Misc -> Clear cache).
- Add a new virtual device, select Google Nexus 5X and Android 6.0 image. It should download a new image from Genymotion website.
  Start created Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920 virtual device.
- Flash Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip (drag&drop the zip file to virtual device window) and then restart the virtual device.
- Flash gapps-L-4-21-15.zip and restart the virtual device again.
- Now add Google account in the virtual device via Settings -> Accounts -> Add account. Do not start Google Play! Ignore any crashes in sign in process.
- Flash benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip and restart the virtual device.
- Open Google Play in virtual device, update all installed applications. - Start Google Now with long touch on home button to force dialog with request to update Google Play Services. Update Google Play Services.
  Now the device is prepared with working Google Play and Google Play Services.
  "

Many say this method works perfectly, and it did for me until I realize the Google Play App is nowhere to be found. I do not know where exactly the Goole Play app is supposed to be but I checked everywhere on this Emulator and it does not contain the Google Play app.

Comment: did you try the new android studio emulator?
there you dont have this problem

Comment: The Android Studio Emulator works very, very slowly for me. @Yoni

Comment: you work on android studio 2.1?
i worked with Genymotion  before a 3 month and this tutorial help me with Google Play Services
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFhStnF42tw

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.2, but I can give it a shot, thank you

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the most versions of gApps on GenyMotion. This is because they release constants bug fixes. You should find the stable version, maybe you have to test with this [gApps gist](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145).