# Can't implement Google Maps in Android project

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

i get that my app won't run without Google Play services,which are missing from your phone. but I have added them as a dependency

Comment: Add running environment first. Is it running at emulator or real device? Did you set up your project in Google and get the API key? Did you ask user to give your access to Internet or GPS? If you can add more detail, you will get more help.

Comment: emulator Google Nexus 5, yeah I did everything according the official android page , it just doesn;t work

Comment: I suffer the similar problems under the emulator test environment. Use a real phone may help you. I am serious about this because the emulator has too many bugs and limitation.

Comment: I have S3 neo and it doesn;t appear in the list of connected devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved by lowering the version of google play services in dependecies, and it now works on the emulator because the latest version 9.4.0 was not compatible with that of the emulator

Answer (score 1):

Check if "play services" are installed and works on your phone. Which version of play services are installed on your phone ?

Comment: I'm using an emulator from genymotion - Google Nexus 5...should I download play services there?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su

Answer (score 1):

Only dependencies is not enough for it; you should have `Google play Services` in the latest version.

You can download Gapps for Emulators in http://opengapps.org/ (select x86 or x86_64 if you can't with ARM) and update them.

Comment: After downloading them, just dump it within the emulator.