# Cannot Add Google Play Services to Genymotion

Tags: android, google-play-services, genymotion

I am attempting to add Google Play Services to Genymotion but having problems. I am following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su), and I run a MacBook Pro. I am receiving the below error when I try and drag and drop the Google Apps file into Genymotion. I am running an HTC device that is using Android 4.3:

[image]

It may have to do with not restarting the emulator propertly. I am simply closing and launching again through Android Studio.

Comment: I remember dragging 2 files onto my emulator and that put Google Play Services on it.

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do, however I am receiving this error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy the popup text? Because that only the progress log, but is not the complete.