# Is there a way to make Jio calls from Wi-Fi connected PC, much like calling from Jio4GVoice app on a Wi-Fi connected Android?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, windows-10, 4g

The Jio4GVoice app (available on Google Play) allows non-4G devices to make VoLTE calls through this app, while being connected via Wi-Fi to the Jio router (4G device).

Is there any way to enable similar calling functionality on a Windows device? Some facts that triggered this thinking:

1. The Windows laptop can be connected  via Wi-Fi to the Jio 4G router.
2. There exists an inbuilt call / phone app on Windows 10 (including PCs).

I've checked, but Jio has no equivalent app on the Windows Store.

I am expecting somebody with knowledge to provide a way to hack around via web protocol, since wi-fi connected Jio4GVoice app talks to the Jio Router via the web protocol only, I am hoping to achieve similar success via a web browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but **may** be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com (and you're more likely to get a good answer there). Please review [the guidelines for posting in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Use Nox player. It works fine, the OTP gets generated to your alternate number. In my laptop (HP P001TX), the voice from my laptop to the other side is very much distorting even though my lap comes with in-built Beats Audio™ You guys try it and give me your feedback

Answer (score 0):

> Never tried this and so can't say it's legal or not according to their
>   policies for making a data call from the laptop or similar device and
>   hence don't recommend this at all, but for the hack part you can try
>   following things which I think should work as it works on your android
>   mobile phone.

First download emulators like genymotion or android emulator through android studio.

After installation you can install all your jio apps to the device through simple drag and drop and connect your laptop to jio router.

make calls from installed emulator in your laptop, this should work.

> please note that : jio apps may depeneds on google services and
>   genymotion does not have them by default and do not support them directly.
>   so you have to follow another procedure defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20137324) to make it
>   work with google play services.

Comment: I actually tried installing Android 6.0, Android 5.0 and Android 4.4 from Android-x86.org, also Remix OS based on the same Android-x86, all of them failed to load the Play Store. All preloaded apps including Chrome loaded fine, which means the problem was specifically with the Play Store. I tried changing the connection type from bridged to NAT, but it did not help. Do you have any idea about this? @vikas

Comment: yes it's a known problem that google play services does not load, but you can try google official emulator but you have to install the android sdk from google first they have support for google play services.

Comment: I managed to run Jio4GVoice on Android x86 inside VMware, but the wifi connection cannot be enabled. I ran the app on bluestacks, and it shows a faux wifi connection as WiFi : Bluestacks. Since the wifi connection is not real, it cannot automatically detect or verify the Jio number. There exists some protocol by which it works, it detects only if the Android device is connected directly to the router, over WiFi. The problem is that internet connection in a guest OS is detected as wired, regardless of what connection type the host uses.

Answer (score -1):

You can download BlueStack for windows and install any android application (for example, Jio 4G Voice) to make voice calls from desktop. The configuration options are same as setting up Jio 4G Voice on Android Smart Phone.

Comment: Please give more explanation in terms of question.

Answer (score -1):

In my knowledge, yes Nox is the best emultor for now for running Jio4gvoice. I tried many other emulators but Jio4g voice won't generate OTP etc etc. Ultimately this is the one that works perfectly as far as Jio4gVoice is concerned without any glitch on Windows 8.1. There is no distortion in sound, no hanging, no issue. Apart from Joi4gvoice you can use whatsapp, truecaller and other apps also on Nox (tested on Lenovo g50_70, i3 laptop with 8 gb RAM, windows 8.1). Only one issue: After you connect to some other network, you need a complete fresh restart of Nox for Jio4gvoice to get online for calls.

I don't think it's illegal to use Jio4gvoice on a Laptop or a PC if you own the PC its OS, Jio connection, wifi and the OTP receiving phone number.