# Sign up with email id and password in android Application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I am trying to sign up a user using Firebase authentication method in my Android application, this is happening:

[image: 1]

It's not registering a user
This is the Registration  code

```
final String _name = txtName.getText().toString().trim();
String _email = txtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
String _pass = txtPass.getText().toString().trim();

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(_name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(_email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(_pass) ) {

    mProgress.setMessage("Registrando ...");
    mProgress.show();

    firAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()) {

               //the user has been registered

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you check account in firebase account section? after few while, showing the registering dialog? it seems like you have registered an account but on success you don't hide the progressbar . . .

Comment: yes @xFighter is correct, do put log and check inside the task.isSuccessfull codition

Comment: check out inside firebase console whether' new user is added or not

Comment: I checked in firebase dashboard . It didn't registered any user .

Answer (score 0):

You are registring the user but not hiding the progress bar after user successfully registered in the firebase. Try applying this code and check the firebase dashboard for authentication. And also Implement onFailureListener to know the reason why user is not being registered.

```
    firAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                     mProgress.dismis();
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                       //the user has been registered
                       Log.d("onSuccess","USER REGISTERED");
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
               @Override
               public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    mProgress.dismis();
                    Log.e("onFailure",e.getMessage());
                }
               }
             );
```

**EDIT**: If you are still facing the same issue go and check these settings in your firebase console authentication tab ,

**Select SIGN-IN METHOD** and Check the status of **Email/Password** if it is **Disable** then switch it to the **Enable**.

And it looks like you are using Genymotion, so have you installed the Google Libraries into your virtual device ?

If not follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su) or test your app on a physical device

Comment: Thanks.
But even after adding the onFailureListener, the same problem persist.

Comment: have you enabled the the authentication in firebase console of your app ?