# Why not getting Android Firebase FCM registration token?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, genymotion

I'm trying to send a push notification to my app from my app server but i'm not getting the FCM registration token through `FirebaseInstanceIdService`. Here i'm using Genymotion personal edition emulator.is that problem with my emulators API?

here is FirebaseInstanceIdService

```
public class FcmInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN),recent_token);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}
 here is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String url = "http://myurl.fcm_insert.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final String token = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN),"");

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Response",error.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("token",token);
                    return params;
                }
            } ;
            Singletone.getSingletone(MainActivity.this).addToRequest(stringRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

it's only sending the default value to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already added the service in your manifest file then you are right it's happening cause of you Genymotion emulators API, then [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su)

Answer (score 1):

**Main Problem is Uninstall first your apk app from your mobile then run and build again from android studio. It helps for me**

If google play services are installed and you are still not getting the token then probably you have implemented your `SharedPreferences` inside `onTokenRefresh()` after the token has been generated. The problem would have been solved automatically if the Application is reinstalled. Remember the `onTokenRefresh()` callback fires whenever a new token is generated. So if the token is already generated `onTokenRefresh()` won't get called.  Only when the token has changed `onTokenRefresh()` method will get called. You can always get the generated token value by calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` almost anywhere in your Application. For your case only you can retrieve the token from `SharedPreferences` as follows:-

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final String token = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN),FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
```

This will ensure that you are always getting the token, and if the token changes `onTokenRefresh()` will get called and your `SharedPreferences` will get updated.

Answer (score 0):

It happen because Genymotion have not google play services by default.

Answer (score 0):

Follo the further instructions to install Google Services on Genymotion, it will take only 10 minutes only

[How to install Google Play Services in a Genymotion VM (with no drag and drop support)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su)