# Can't get Firebase Notifications in Genymotion Emulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, genymotion

My application not receiving any notifications installed on genymotion emulator.
Firebase Token is not generating.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581532/why-not-getting-android-firebase-fcm-registration-token

Answer (score 6):

Genymotion by default does not come with Google Play Services installed. Firebase requires Play Services to work.

To install, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20137324/2234894

Comment: Correct, if you checked all users from OneSignal dashboard you will notice that your Android Genymotion is not subscribed yet to push notification due to the lack of Google Play Services like said above.