# Flashed virtual genymotion device and can't launch apks no more?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, genymotion

I've flashed a virtual device so it can have Google Play services. And since then I can't launch .apks from Android studio. I'm not sure if I flashed it incorrectly or what. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Android studio emulators and virtual devices have already support for Google Play services with many versions of android. Why did you flashed it?

Comment: I used genymotion as the emulator as I don't have Intel cpu. And the emulators don't have google play services pre installed

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for other methods of putting Google Play services on gMotion

Comment: Did you tried these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su

Comment: Yes these are the posts I used. But once I've done this I can't run an .apk using Android studio it prompts me to uninstall the apk for it to work but it doesn't :(

Comment: I'll continue it tomorrow. Its late here at the moment

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks

Comment: You can answer your own question and approve if you have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the guide provided by genymotion.

Visit http://opengapps.org

And do the following

Select x86 as platform
Select appropriate Android version 
Select nano

Simply drag downloaded zip file not to emulator display.

(Source)
https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#google-play-services