# android emulator with google play services at docker

Tags: android, docker

I want to create a dockerfile that creates an android emulator with version 7-8 and google play services
Does anyone know how can i do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe** you can use some android emulator(like a [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)) and set up a Google play services inside. But Genymotion doesn't provide Google apps and 
[you must set up it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121883/how-to-install-google-play-services-in-a-genymotion-vm-with-no-drag-and-drop-su) using a ARM Translation Installer.

If you want **only run** android apps on docker, you should look at [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/ksoichiro/android-emulator/).