# Firebase messaging.getToken() fails with MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE error

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase, android-devicetoken

I am trying to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging into an ongoing project. I followed the guide for installation [here](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage) and installed both @react-native-firebase/app and @react-native-firebase/messaging.
However, when I attempt to get device token with `await messaging.getToken()` it fails with this warning -NativeFirebaseError: [messaging/unknown] MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE

Please note that if I send a push notification from firebase console, it gets delivered on a real phone, which shows that the issues is probably not with the FCM set up.

Any helpful suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 8):

is emulator have you installed google play???
cause the device cannot generate token without google play.
in geymotion: To install, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20137324/2234894