# Installing Google play/Chrome browser on genymotion

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

I wanted to use Chrome on android emulator so I installed GenyMotion.

I installed the latest version 2.0.3 and downloaded "Nexus 7 - 4.2.2" ROM.

I followed the folowing links
[How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virtu)

But neither drag n drop is working nor I am able to install the Google Appz from within the emulator.
http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/

After downloading "gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip" and when the I select the file within emulator it comes with "There is no app registered to handle the type of file selected"

When I try to drag and drop the file from my PC to Oracle VM running ROM it is just not working. File is not dropping
I referred the following link as well
[Genymotion 2.0 "drag and drop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002138/genymotion-2-0-drag-and-drop)

Comment: Please elaborate on "drag and drop" is not working, it should, which OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: I am using Windows XP.

As mentioned in the following link I downloaded the files to install the Google Play and after downloading I have to drop the files on the running Virtual device.
http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/

I selected the "Bidirectional" in DragnDrop on Oracle VM VirtualBox for the Virtual Device still I am not able to drop the file on Virtual device. When I try to drop the file it comes with a different mouse pointer which normally appears when dropping is not supported.

Comment: To fix DnD issue I followed the following article but without success
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002138/genymotion-2-0-drag-and-drop

Comment: I am not sure how well Windows XP is at emulation, probably not very good, even if drag and drop works, or if @nitin-mukesh solution works, still it will work poorly due to lack of support by the OS for virtualization

Comment: Actually none of the steps mentioned in articles are working. I just need to check couple of issues on Android 4.2 and above and any of the tab I have are not upgradeable beyond 4.1.2. :(

Is there any otheer alternative.

Comment: Replace Windows XP with Windows 7/8

Comment: unfortunately on Windows 7 its not working at all. When I launch the android virtual device through Oracle VM VirtualBox it just keep showing error on console and never launch.

Comment: I have the same issue with mac osX and I am using api18.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

- install the libhoudini mentioned in this guide:
  [[GUIDE] Genymotion | Installing ARM Translation and GApps[Updated Nov.16]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952)
  I experienced the DnD issue as well, read below for how I worked around it
  I did *not* install the GAPPs zip. It's not needed and causes a lot of crash notifications.
- Extract up-to-date Chrome APK from my actual android device. APK's for installed apps can be found in /data/app (but this my require root) or you could use a back-up solution to extract it.
- Install the obtained APK by also DnD'ing it into the home screen, it will automatically install.
  ... And it worked.

As for the DnD issue, in my case the cause appeared to be that I was running Genymotion 'as administrator' (Why? Complicated: Because I have an unrelated virtualBox machine using a native disk image, which requires me to start virtualbox in privileged mode, which will crash Genymotion if it's not also running in privileged mode). However when I started GenyMotion not 'as admin' the dnd issue did not appear.
If this is not the issue in your case I think you can still get the stuff installed without DnD support:

- First get the files on your image in some way, use your imagination (or any file sharing web service)
- Also get an APK for a decent file explorer with ZIP and root support. I use ES file explorer and my instructions will be based in it. I suggest, as for Chrome itself, to install it on your actual phone first and then grab the APK.
- Install the file explorer, start it and become root (ES crashed the first couple of times in my case, but after some tries it worked)
- make sure /system is mounted as r/w. in ES, use menu->root explorer->mount R/W, put /system on RW
- Locate the Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip, browse into it, select (long press) 'system' folder, extract to, 'choose path', point to /. The Zip will now be 'installed'
- Go back to root explorer options, put /system back to RO
- Reboot the emulator (in my case it crashed both on shutdown and first boot; I just closed the emulator after a few minutes and tried again. Then it worked)
- Now you should be able to install the Chrome APK