# How to use Genymotion Drag & Drop support on OS X?

Tags: android, macos, genymotion

I just downloaded Genymotion 2.2 after re-installing OS X on my laptop and can no longer use drag and drop in Genymotion. Previously I had Ubuntu installed and everything worked out of the box. Now that I have re-installed OS X, every time I drag and drop a file in Genymotion I get this error:

```
Invalid filename: 
/.file/id=6571367.1120489
```

Most posts I have read tell you to enable drag and drop from VirtualBox (I did) and enable folder sharing (also did this) or mention some other error meaning that ADB isn't setup properly (I even downloaded the Android SDK and pointed Genymotion to a custom SDK path that it accepted).

Has anyone else ever come across this error? I haven't been able to find any other posts in about 15-20 minutes of searching. I've attached a screenshot, just in case.

[image: Error message]

EDIT: If I create the file path (/.file/id=6571367.1120489), Genymotion copied it to /sdcard/download as "id=6571367.1120489." I had hoped doing a chmod would work by giving my normal user permissions to write to the path (Why would Genymotion be setup to use /.file/, anyway?), if I don't drag and drop a file with the name from the error message, it does not transfer. Even when it does transfer, it does not flash or install the file which is what I am trying to do. I've been trying to flash the ARM translation zip.

I also know that ADB is working because I manually pushed the contents of the ARM translation zip and gapps package.

Comment: This answer worked for me. =D http://stackoverflow.com/a/20266878/2823832

Answer (score 1):

there is easy solution:

1. adb remount
2. adb push /Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1/system /system
3. adb push /gapps-kk-20140105-signed/system /system
4. reboot device

Done!